# Same item being modified and accessed by workflows simultaneously

Tags: 2010, workflow

A general question, I wonder if the following will cause any issue.

There are 2 workflows associated to a list item, both set to trigger on item modified. First workflow updates a field and committe to the item, while the second workflow queries the same item to read some data off it.

I konw 2 workflows updating the same item will surely be problematic. But in my case, can SharePoint handle it or will there still be issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be issues.  If needed, put your processes into one workflow with different steps.  You can pause for a duration if you need to wait for the information to change.  The timer job for for workflow is 5 minutes by default, and even though you can lower it to 1, it will still take 5 minutes for the pause to run.  Try not to use too many pauses.  I have used JSLink or SPServices to modify list items to trigger workflows based off of list changes.  This helps lower the amount of processes I have running on the list, which in turn, makes it more efficient and less likely to fail.